# why I can't update this model in Yii?

Tags: php, validation, yii, model

I am using Yii framework, I want to update a model by clicking on link that calls an action in the controller, this action is used to modify some attributes of the model then if the modification is done, it should be redirect to another action. My problem is the model update doesn't saved and I don't know why, here is my code:

view code:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>category</th>
            <th>published</th>
            <th>priority</th>
            <th>in news banner</th>
            <th>publish</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$x=0;
if(!empty($model)){

    foreach ($model as $m){
        $x++;
        echo "<tr>
            <td>$x</td>
            <td>$m->title</td>
                <td>$m->category</td>
                    <td>$m->display</td>
                        <td>$m->priority</td>
                            <td>$m->newsBanner</td>
                        <td><a href='".Yii::app()->createUrl('articles/approve', array('id'=>$m->id, 'c'=>$c))."'><button id='btn$m->id'>Publish</button></a></td>
                </tr>"; 
    }
}
?>
    </tbody></table>
```

action code:

```
public function actionApprove($id, $c)
    {

        $artilce = $this->loadModel($id);

        if(!empty($artilce)){

            $article->category = 'anything';
            $article->validate();
            print_r($artilce->getErrors());
            if($artilce->save())

                $this->redirect(array('pending', 'c'=>$c));
        }
    }
```

model rules code:

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('text, category, display, newsBanner, priority, title, visits, previewText, idUser, homepage', 'required'),
            array('idUser, homepage', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('visits', 'numerical'),
            array('category, priority', 'length', 'max'=>50),
            array('display, newsBanner', 'length', 'max'=>3),
            array('date', 'safe'),
            array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, JPG, png, PNG, gif, GIF', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, text, category, display, newsBanner, priority, date, title, visits, previewText, image, caption, idUser, homepage', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

I got empty array from `getErrors()`, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validate()` method clears errors after calling (as a default behavior). If you take a look at the official document you will see:

```
public boolean validate(array $attributes=NULL, boolean $clearErrors=true)
```

> **$attributes**: list of attributes that should be validated. Defaults to null, meaning any attribute listed in the applicable validation rules should be validated. If this parameter is given as a list of attributes, only the listed attributes will be validated.
>
> **$clearErrors**: whether to call clearErrors before performing validation

`$clearErrors` is set to `TRUE` by default. So there will be no error in your `getErrors()` method, after calling `validation()` method.

Try:

```
if($article->validate()){
    //then save 
}
```

or:

```
$article->validate(NULL,FALSE);
//check errors
```

Comment: @MD.MD you have also a typo mistake: `$artilce->save()` should be `$article->save()`

Comment: DAMN !! thats it, its just a misspelling mistake

Comment: @MD.MD :)) Glad it worked. however, `$model->getErrors()` will be always empty, after calling `$model->validate()` :)